# why this functions can't be found outside the setInterval loop? (javascript)

Tags: javascript

I'm using [planetaryjs](http://planetaryjs.com/) package to draw a globe in js.

There's a function `planetary.plugins.pings.add`. It works when it's in this loop:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var lat = 30.2500;
    var lng = 120.1667;
    var color = 'white';
    globe.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, { color: color, ttl: 30000, angle: Math.random() * 10 });
}, 200);
```

But I only want to draw one ping, so I did

```
    var lat = 30.2500;
    var lng = 120.1667;
    var color = 'white';
    globe.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, { color: color, ttl: 30000, angle: Math.random() * 10 });
```

But firefox tells me

```
TypeError: globe.plugins.pings is undefined
```

Does somebody know why is this? Complete code is here (see line 67-77). Source is [here](http://planetaryjs.com/examples/rotating.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://labs.rivendellweb.net/data-vis/planetary/planetaryjs.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

    <canvas id='rotatingGlobe' width='800' height='600' style='width: 800px; height: 600px; cursor: move;'></canvas>
        <script>

            (function() {

                      var globe = planetaryjs.planet();

                      // Load our custom `autorotate` plugin; see below.
                      globe.loadPlugin(autorotate(0));

                      // The `earth` plugin draws the oceans and the land; it's actually
                      // a combination of several separate built-in plugins.
                      // Note that we're loading a special TopoJSON file
                      // (world-110m-withlakes.json) so we can render lakes.
                      globe.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.earth({
                        topojson: { file:   'world-110m-withlakes.json' },
                        oceans:   { fill:   '#000080' },
                        land:     { fill:   '#339966' },
                        borders:  { stroke: '#008000' }
                      }));

                      // Load our custom `lakes` plugin to draw lakes; see below.
                      globe.loadPlugin(lakes({
                        fill: '#000080'
                      }));

                      // The `pings` plugin draws animated pings on the globe.
                      globe.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.pings());

                      // The `zoom` and `drag` plugins enable
                      // manipulating the globe with the mouse.
                      globe.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.zoom({
                        scaleExtent: [100, 2000]
                      }));
                      globe.loadPlugin(planetaryjs.plugins.drag({
                        // Dragging the globe should pause the
                        // automatic rotation until we release the mouse.
                        onDragStart: function() {
                          this.plugins.autorotate.pause();
                        },
                        onDragEnd: function() {
                          this.plugins.autorotate.resume();
                        }
                      }));

                      // Set up the globe's initial scale, offset, and rotation.
                      globe.projection
                            .scale(400)
                            .translate([400, 300])
                            .rotate([-100, -30, 0]);

                      // Every few hundred milliseconds, we'll draw another random ping.
                      //var colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'white', 'orange', 'green', 'cyan', 'pink'];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var lat = 30.2500;
                            var lng = 120.1667;
                            var color = 'white';
                            globe.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, { color: color, ttl: 30000, angle: Math.random() * 10 });
                        }, 200);

                            var lat = 30.2500;
                            var lng = 120.1667;
                            var color = 'white';
                            globe.plugins.pings.add(lng, lat, { color: color, ttl: 30000, angle: Math.random() * 10 });

                      var canvas = document.getElementById('rotatingGlobe');
                      // Special code to handle high-density displays (e.g. retina, some phones)
                      // In the future, Planetary.js will handle this by itself (or via a plugin).
                      if (window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {
                        canvas.width = 800;
                        canvas.height = 800;
                        context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        context.scale(2, 2);
                      }
                      // Draw that globe!
                      globe.draw(canvas);

                      // This plugin will automatically rotate the globe around its vertical
                      // axis a configured number of degrees every second.
                      function autorotate(degPerSec) {
                        // Planetary.js plugins are functions that take a `planet` instance
                        // as an argument...
                        return function(planet) {
                          var lastTick = null;
                          var paused = false;
                          planet.plugins.autorotate = {
                            pause:  function() { paused = true;  },
                            resume: function() { paused = false; }
                          };
                          // ...and configure hooks into certain pieces of its lifecycle.
                          planet.onDraw(function() {
                            if (paused || !lastTick) {
                              lastTick = new Date();
                            } else {
                              var now = new Date();
                              var delta = now - lastTick;
                              // This plugin uses the built-in projection (provided by D3)
                              // to rotate the globe each time we draw it.
                              var rotation = planet.projection.rotate();
                              rotation[0] += degPerSec * delta / 1000;
                              if (rotation[0] >= 180) rotation[0] -= 360;
                              planet.projection.rotate(rotation);
                              lastTick = now;
                            }
                          });
                        };
                      };

                      // This plugin takes lake data from the special
                      // TopoJSON we're loading and draws them on the map.
                      function lakes(options) {
                        options = options || {};
                        var lakes = null;

                        return function(planet) {
                          planet.onInit(function() {
                            // We can access the data loaded from the TopoJSON plugin
                            // on its namespace on `planet.plugins`. We're loading a custom
                            // TopoJSON file with an object called "ne_110m_lakes".
                            var world = planet.plugins.topojson.world;
                            lakes = topojson.feature(world, world.objects.ne_110m_lakes);
                          });

                          planet.onDraw(function() {
                            planet.withSavedContext(function(context) {
                              context.beginPath();
                              planet.path.context(context)(lakes);
                              context.fillStyle = options.fill || 'black';
                              context.fill();
                            });
                          });
                        };
                      };
                    })();


        </script>





  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace setInterval by setTimeout.

The reason your direct call fails is because globe.plugins.pings is not initialized till after `globe.draw(canvas);` is called. You could also move it to after this.

When compared to replacing it by the code block, setTimeout moves the execution of the code block to the end of the execution queue i.e. till after globe.draw(canvas); is called and globe.plugins.pings is initialized - but unlike setInterval, it runs only once.

Comment: works like a charm. thank you so much! do yo mean the globe object is not fully initialized? Is this something common? Could you recommend something to read about this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is mostly a guess, but I assume that there could be either some asynchronous operation (like an AJAX call to get data to draw the globe) that happens or something further down your program defines the object you are trying to call. You get the error because at the point in time you called it, it was undefined.

Comment: Thanks @potatopeelings do you mean the order of code is improper? the object `globe` was defined at the first line of the code...

Comment: Globe was defined, but try doing a console. Log of globe.plugins.pings

Comment: undefined... `globe.plugins` is an empty thing {}... I need to pick up something more about this. thanks man!

Comment: @user2864740 - removing the setInterval and directly running the function is what broke it initially as per the question.

Answer (score 3):

it would be better to use some sort of callback rather than just replying on a random timeout.
Something like this.
`planet.onInit( function([done]){} )`

Answer (score 1):

The DOM is not initialized at the point of execution, you should wrap the initialization in `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { /* your code here */ });`

Comment: It does not appear to be 'the DOM content', but rather some library - and the loading of such is independent, except where a relationship has been established.

Comment: Hmm, but the <script>s don't have a `defer` or `async` attribute, so everything should be loaded by the time the DOM is loaded... some library seems to load stuff asynchronously, I will dig into this :-)

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tzksw9oh/) and it results in some JSON error message, someone should be using POST instead of GET

Comment: I can't get it to work even [in plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/B6GAr566IDMuY7n34uRE?p=preview), the `pings` plugin seems not to be loaded

Comment: thanks for discussion guys! shouldn't the plugins be loaded in the <head> where I quote the package?